# Get Opportunity based on contact under the account

Tags: opportunity

I am expecting Opportunity in table (vf page) from contact and this contact is under the account.

can anybody help me out for this...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be elaborate your question? And possible post any code which you have so far.

Comment: Thank you for reply but i got the solution. @Goki

Comment: @Nihar In that case please post your solution as answer and mark it as answer, so that it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i the solution of my question,

I am expecting the opportunity record and it Should only show opportunities at the account for the logged in contact.

```
oppData = new List<Opportunity>();
oppData = [SELECT ID, Name, Tax_rate__c,Billing_Street__c,Owner.Name,AccountID,Account.Name,Order__c,StageName,CloseDate FROM Opportunity
           WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId from Contact WHERE Name =: contactName)];
```